# Create variable syntax highlighting for c++ st3

Tags: c++, regex, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

So I want to implement variable syntax highlighting for my custom c++ theme on sublime text 3. So I wanted to create a custom scope  to then use on my tmTheme file so I went to add to the default sublime text c++ syntax and added this to detect variables:

**c++.sublime-syntax:**

```
contexts:
  main:
    - include: preprocessor-global
    - include: global

  # my custom scope
  normal-variables:
    - match: '([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\ +=|;))'
      captures: 
        1: variable.other.name.member.c++
        2: variable.other.name.end.c++
```

Here is my **objective**:
if string contains uppercase,lowercase, numbers **AND** is in the form of string -> one space or more -> one equal sign(=) **OR** the string just has a semicolon it is captured.

And so in this case I have two capture groups the first one will match the variable name and will be considered as *variable.other.name.member.c++* and the second group will be the semicolon or the equal and additional spaces and would be considered as *variable.other.name.end.c++*.

Here are some examples of what I expect from sublime text to recognize as variables and assign them the custom scopes I included in the sublime-syntax file:

```cpp
//var has to be captured
int var = //in the format anyVarName = 
//or
int var;//in the format anyVarName;
```

Now I saved this file and tried to show the scope of a variable and it just recognize it as a source.c++ so my code does not work, would you guys have any ideas?.Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sample file looks like a combination of a `tmLanguage` syntax definition as well as a `tmTheme` color scheme. You're correct in that you would need to modify the syntax definition to recognize the thing you want to color so that your color scheme can target it, but it needs to be a part of two separate files. The C++ syntax is a `sublime-syntax` file and not a `tmLanguage` file, and editing it to include a rule for this is non-trivial, which is why the current syntax definition doesn't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your response @OdatNurd , I didn’t know that it was supposed to be in two different files, thank you for the heads up. Now to make it work what you are saying is I need to put my custom scope with the regex inside a sublime-syntax file and then use it in a tmLanguage/tmTheme file? If yes, would I have to create a sublime-syntax file or edit my theme sublime-syntax file and add the c++ regex there?

Comment: The C++ syntax is a `sublime-syntax` file, so you'd need to modify the existing syntax to also include your rule here so that it will apply the scope. Then you can add the rule to your color scheme to get it to color. However, adding an additional rule to a syntax definition is not as straight forward as adding a new rule to a color scheme.

Comment: Hi @OdatNurd, thanks again for your answer, I have now updated my post accordingly please see above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your ultimate goal is to add syntax highlighting to the names of variables at the point where they're declared ***but nowhere else in the file***, unfortunately you can't do what you're trying to do here.

The reason for this is that the rules in a syntax definition determine what the different portions of the file represent based solely on the context in which they're found and recognized in the input file without keeping any (usable) record of what the text meant.

As such, except for the point where the variable is declared, there's nothing to tell the syntax definition that the name of the variable is special so that it can apply the same scope later.

To help illustrate this, here's some sample nonsense code, as highlighted by the existing C++ syntax definition:

```cpp
#define var X
int var = 10;
var = 29;
```

[image: Syntax highlighting definition]

In line one, the syntax definition sees that there's a `#define` token, which means that this is the start of a preprocessor directive. Based on that, it knows that the `var` in that line is the name of a macro, and it gets assigned the scope `source.c++ meta.preprocessor.macro.c++ entity.name.constant.preprocessor.c++`, which lets the syntax highlighter know that this is a named entity that's a preprocessor value; the rule for that in my color scheme colors it as green.

However the fact that `var` is special isn't retained anywhere because Sublime isn't compiling the code, it's just looking at it lexically (as a series of tokens).

Hence on line 2 although it can determine that `int` is an internal type, that `=` is an operator and that `10` is a number, it doesn't remember that `var` used to be a preprocessor directive. There isn't a rule that marks it as a variable, so it's just considered to be unscoped text.

It's certainly possible to apply a rule that would trigger on line 2 and apply your scope to the text `var`; in that specific line it can be inferred that it's probably the name of a variable in the same way that line 1 can tell that it's a preprocessor macro.

The reason that the default syntax doesn't do that already is because it would only allow for syntax highlighting `var` in the line where it's declared and nowhere else, which isn't terribly helpful.

For similar reasons, custom types defined via a `typedef` aren't recognized in variable declarations either. You may also notice that the name of a class is recognized as such in the class definition, constructor and destructor, but not as a return type in methods, and when invoking the constructor it's seen as a function call instead.

The reason your syntax adjustment above doesn't have any effect on anything is because it provides a new context but doesn't include it anywhere, so it's effectively disabled. How syntax definitions work is fairly complicated, but in short you've provided a new named set (`context`) of `match` rules, but without telling the syntax definition where they should be applied, they have no effect on anything.